# using value in useState but when I use it in this.state the switch between tabs not happening

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, redux

- I am trying to make the tabs work in a class component way.
- they are using value in useState but when I use it in this.state the switch between tabs not happening.
- I referred the below two articles but still not helping me
  https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html
  https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/making-sense-of-react-hooks-fdbde8803889
- I debugged the code here handleChange is printing console.log("handleChange--->");
- providing my code snippet and sandbox below.

```or-tag-here
class SimpleTabs extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      selectedButton: false,
      value: 0
    };

    // const classes = useStyles();
    // const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);
  }

  handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
    // const classes = useStyles();
    console.log("handleChange--->");
    const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);
    setValue(newValue);
  };

  render() {
    //const classes = useStyles();
    const { classes } = this.props;
    //  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);

    return (
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <AppBar position="static">
          <Tabs value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}>
            <Tab label="Item One" />
            <Tab label="Item Two" />
            <Tab label="Item Three" />
          </Tabs>
        </AppBar>
        {this.state.value === 0 && <TabContainer>Item One</TabContainer>}
        {this.state.value === 1 && <TabContainer>Item Two</TabContainer>}
        {this.state.value === 2 && <TabContainer>Item Three</TabContainer>}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withStyles(styles)(SimpleTabs);
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use hooks inside of class components, just functional components. Instead, use this.state and this.setState.

```
  handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
    this.setState({
      value: newValue;
    });
  };
```

Alternatively, you could rewrite your component as a functional component (i've omitted selected button, because i don't see it used anywhere):

```
const SimpleTabs = (props) => {
  const { classes } = props;
  const [value, setValue] = useState(0);

  const handleChange = useCallback((event, newValue) => {
    setValue(newValue);
  }, [])

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <AppBar position="static">
        <Tabs value={value} onChange={handleChange}>
          <Tab label="Item One" />
          <Tab label="Item Two" />
          <Tab label="Item Three" />
        </Tabs>
      </AppBar>
      {value === 0 && <TabContainer>Item One</TabContainer>}
      {value === 1 && <TabContainer>Item Two</TabContainer>}
      {value === 2 && <TabContainer>Item Three</TabContainer>}
    </div>
  );
}
```